# How do I pass information my a controller to a view in PHP (no framework)?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Using PHP, If I have a model (a class) where I various queries, whatever I need, and in my controller, I use myModel = new CustomerModel(); and later in the controller, say I call myMyodel in the controller (I know looks like codeigniter but I am not using a framework) to:

$data['query'] = myModel.OrderByLastName();

how do I pass that $data['query'] to a view, a separate .php page?

I don't wan to echo anything from my controller.

Also, was hoping this design, the way I explained it makes sense.  Or am I wasting time with the model class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you'd instantiate a view object:

```
$view = new View();
```

Pass it the info it needs():

```
$view->set($name1, $value1);
$view->set($name2, $value2);
...
```

Then invoke the view's renderer:

```
$view->render();
```

Comment: Neither, it's just what you might call such a function in your own view layer code. I.e., I'm assuming that you're going to write the View class yourself. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

The way Django works is the controller basically renders a template using a templating system.  It passes the data in Contexts, like this:

```
data['query'] = myModel.OrderByLastName();

context = {'data': data['query']}

page = loader.get_template('folder/template.phtml')

return render_to_page(page, context)
```

roughly.

Obviously, you're writing your own system so you've got some room on exactly how you implement it.  I don't know if that's exactly what you want, but it might give you a workable idea.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know for sure.  I just wanted to know how to call another PHP page and send the information to it.